# Can not use GPU with tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nvidia

I have installed tensorflow-gpu, and followed the tensorflow's guide for installing cuda, and the other necessary components in order to use the gpu for training.

This is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

[image: This is the output of nvidia-smi]

And this is the output in Jupyter:

[image]

Comment: You need to look at the tensorflow logs, produced when you import and use tensorflow, they will tell you why the GPU is not detected and if any libraries are missing.

Comment: Which tutorial did you use? Are there any log messages when importing Tensorflow? Are you using Anaconda?

Comment: I am not using anaconda, and the log isn't reporting any missing libraries. I followed the guide on the official tensorflow-gpu docs website, in the Windows section.

Comment: @Aleksandar Ivanovski, Is your issue resolved now? Else can you let me know steps you have followed to install tensorflow and version details of TF, CUDA, CuDNN? So that we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: I still haven't resolved the issue, first of all I installed CUDA, then CuDNN and finally i set up a virtual environment with tensorflow installed. And TF, still can't detect my GPU.

Comment: @Aleksandar Ivanovski, can you let us know version details of TF, CUDA and CuDNN ?